# Maclaurin expansion for $~x^a~(1-x)^b~$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, beta-function

How to use a Maclaurin Series Expansion on $~x^a~(1-x)^b~$?

There is a singularity at $~x = 0~$ when derivatives are taken.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Regardless of aesthetics, unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: Aside from my above comment, [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maclaurin+series+of+%28x%5Ea%29%281-x%29%5Eb) will quickly give you the answer in several forms.

Comment: WolframAlpha does not work at all. By plugging 0 into f^(n)(x), it gives out 0 simply. So one must take the limit.

Comment: a and b are real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1-x)^b=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{b}k (-x)^k$$
$$\therefore x^a(1-x)^b=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{b}k (-1)^k x^{a+k}$$
This expansion is valid for $-1\le x\le1$ where $x,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $a\not\in\mathbb{N}^0$ then this becomes a Puiseux series.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am doing research related to Beta Function and you really saved my life!

Comment: That is not a Maclaurin series for non-integral $a$.

Comment: @MartinR there does not exist a Maclaurin series expansion for non-integral $a$ because $f^{(\lceil a\rceil)}(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Is there a way to take a limit? That can be helpful!

Comment: Puiseux series is amazing! Thank you

Comment: But is it approaching -1 for some rational numbers?

Comment: Like(-1/n)^(-1/n) when n is an odd number approaching infinity

Comment: No I mean that you would have to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} x^y$ for some constant $y\lt0$ which is not possible as the limit does not exist.

Comment: I might have more questions coming tomorrow. THANK YOU. Have a good night

Comment: I see. I will think about it tomorrow again. I still think it is possible.